# Swift 3 scrollToRowAtIndexPath became scrollToRow

Tags: swift3

I am converting a Swift 2.3 project o Swift 3 and digging through literally thousands of changes

I currently have code like this:

```
outletCatalog.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(myIndex, atScrollPoisition: .top, animated: false)
```

However, it is apparently replaced by

```
func scrollToRow(at: IndexPath, at: UITableViewScrollPosition, animated: Bool)
```

However - I don't understand the double parameter naming of *"at"* and my Google searches did not yield anything. And code translation tools just shows it has

```
scrollToRow(at:at:animated)
```

Answer (score 15):

After code conversion from **Swift 2.3** to **Swift 3.2** version, you need to call below code inside `GCD main dispatch block` with the new changes for auto scroll row to index.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
   let index = IndexPath(row: 10, section: 0) // use your index number or Indexpath
   self.tableCart.scrollToRow(at: index,at: .middle, animated: true) //here .middle is the scroll position can change it as per your need
}
```

*I hope it will work for you.*

---

> **Support** - **Swift 3.1, 3.2, 4.1**

Comment: Good stuff. Works Swift 5.1, iOS 12.2.

Answer (score 2):

According to the API Reference Docs, scrollToRow(at:at:animated:) scrolls through the table view until a row identified by index path is at a particular location on the screen. The first argument is of type IndexPath (which specifies the section, and the row, to scroll to). The second argument, an enum value of type UITableViewScrollPosition, specifies where the row is placed at the end of the scroll (top/middle/bottom of the screen). The third argument just animates the process.

In your code, you have:

```
outletCatalog.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(myIndex, atScrollPosition: .top, animated: false)
```

Which can be replaced with:

```
outletCatalog.scrollToRow(at: myIndex, at: .top, animated: false)
```

For more, look here:
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableview/1614997-scrolltorow
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewscrollposition